# If $f$ is isometry and triple composition of $f$ is identity, then $f$ has a fixed point.

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, isometry

### Let $f$ be isometry. If $f \circ f \circ f$ is identity, prove that $f$ has a fixed point.

I know that $f$, since it is an isometry, is a composition of at most three reflections, but I have no idea how to use it here.

There is another theorem I came accross that says:

*If $f$ does not leave any point fixed, then $f$ is either a translation, or the composite of a translation and a rotation, or the composite of a translation, a rotation, and a reflection through a line.*

I am not sure how to prove either of those, and whether the latter would maybe be the answer to the former.

Comment: What's the domain of $f$? The statement is cetainly false if the domain is, say, a circle.

Comment: It is not specified in the question, but I suppose the whole Euclidean plane by definition of Euclidean plane isometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you are talking about isometries of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to the usual metric. Am I right?

If so, either $f$ preserves the orientation or it reverses it. If it reverses it, so does $f\circ f\circ f$, but this cannot be, since $f\circ f\circ f$ is the identity. Therefore, $f$ preserves the orientation. In other words, it is either a rotation or a translation. If it is a rotation, of course that it has a fixed point. And if it is a non-trivial translation, then $f\circ f\circ f$ is also a non-trivial translation, and therefore not it is the identity.

Comment: Yes, you are right! These are the only isometries I have learned about so I apologize if my question was not precise enough.  Thank you very much, it is clear now!

Comment: @milaid If my answer was helpful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Begging for points is unbecoming.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(P)=Q$, $f(Q)=R$, so $f(R)=P$, and consider the circumcenter of the triangle $PQR$.